# Can't install fasttext on docker container

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, docker-build, fasttext

I am trying to build a python docker container.

Here is my dockerfile:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3.8-slim
WORKDIR /src
COPY req.ini req.ini
RUN apt-get update
RUN pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
RUN pip install -r req.ini
COPY . .
CMD ["python3","flask","run","--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

and in my req.ini file looks like this:

Flask
fasttext
gensim
nltk
scipy
pandas
numpy

But when I run docker build --tag python-app. , I get the following error:

```
#15 11.25   Building wheel for fasttext (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
#15 11.26   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
#15 11.26
#15 11.26   × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
#15 11.26   │ exit code: 1
#15 11.26   ╰─> [42 lines of output]

#15 11.26   ERROR: Failed building wheel for fasttext
#15 11.26   Running setup.py clean for fasttext
#15 11.38 Failed to build fasttext
#15 15.60   Running setup.py install for fasttext: finished with status 'error'
#15 15.61   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
#15 15.61
#15 15.61   × Running setup.py install for fasttext did not run successfully.
#15 15.61   │ exit code: 1
#15 15.61   ╰─> [46 lines of output]
#15 15.61       /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py:731: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'description_file' instead

#15 15.61 × Encountered error while trying to install package.
#15 15.61 ╰─> fasttext
#15 15.61
#15 15.61 note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.

------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pip install -r req.ini]: exit code: 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, based on the documentation, fastText requires pybind11 as well. can you try to add this package to your req.ini ?
Documentation : https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/python-module.html

Comment: I added pybind11 to req.ini but unfortunately, the error persists.

Comment: Hi again, I took your Dockerfile and req.ini to reproduce the problem, In the error lines, it says, `RuntimeError: Unsupported compiler -- at least C++11 support is needed!`

So, I added Dockerfile `RUN apt-get install build-essential -y` step and It is builded successfully. Can you try this?

Comment: Yup, it worked. Thank your very much. Stack did not allowed me to post the whole error because I did not have a lot of text in the post, so I had to cut that part.

Comment: No problem, glad it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to `Dockerfile` to get the C++11 package:

```
RUN apt-get update &&\
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends --yes build-essential
```